# checked/unchecked checkbox when row selection already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

My checkbox does not work (**Not checked**) when I have selected row table.

This is my *row selection*.

```
$('#mainTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   });
```

I have included handler for checkbox, but no luck.

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, dataIndex){
         var rowId = data[0];

         if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
            $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(row).addClass('selected');
         }
      }
```

[Reference](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/)

[**JSFiddle Demonstration**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/6aw67czc/)

Comment: *"does not work"* doesn't explain expected behavior or a specific problem

Comment: when I have selected row table, checkbox not checked. you can see in the fiddle

Comment: Are you saying you want checkbox to be checked/unchecked when click anywhere in row?

Comment: yes, i try adding handler but it makes my table not display..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hasClass()` to check current selected state and use that to toggle checkbox

```
$('#mainTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        var $row=$(this), 
            isSelected = $row.hasClass('selected')
        $row.toggleClass('selected')
            .find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isSelected);
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6aw67czc/1/)